# Can this question be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

With the recent introduction of the Lifejacket and Lifeboat badges—and the disappearance of Tumbleweed—it occurred to me today that I ought to post a meta bounty on my own [Tumbleweed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174609/was-jack-kirbys-later-comic-book-art-influenced-by-his-work-on-concept-art-for) question.  However, when I pulled it up, I found that it had been deleted *sub silentio* by Community.  I would still be interested in getting an answer about the effect of his concept work on the *Lord of Light* film on Jack Kirby's later work.  So I can get this one undeleted?

Comment: Seems you got the necessary votes.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yeah, thanks for marking it status-completed.